# Since I am unemployed, can I get PR card any faster?

Tags: canada, immigration

I arrived in Canada on a closed work permit (on GSS) but was terminated in less than a year because of the pandemic. I appeared for IELTS over and over again, and eventually got picked up in express entry for Permanent Residency. I have submitted all the documents, but my friends (and website) say it will take about 4 months to process the application.

Is there a way to get my PR card faster, I have interviews lined up and I don't want to miss those opportunities.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question on a bureaucratic process and not a question on the law.

Comment: Previously posted at Expatriates.SE, which is the proper place for it: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21264/since-i-am-unemployed-can-i-get-pr-card-any-faster.  In the future, if you crosspost between SE sites, make sure each copy contains a link to the other, to avoid people needlessly duplicating their efforts.